# Arabic Language indent is getting changed while storing in notes document body field

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

When we take an Arabic language string and assigning the string to `Notes Document` (body fields) the indent of string is getting changed, means the Arabic string is in right to left when it getting stored in body (of `Notes Document`) it is displaying as left to right.

For eg function:

```
public bool assign_property_to_mail(NotesDocument MailDocument, Mail objmail)
{
      MailDocument.AppendItemValue(objmail.Body, "Body"); 
}
```

`objmail` is a type of object in which all mail properties can be stored and `.body` is object property where content of mail body which is in Arabic language is present & `Notes Document` is an instance of IBM Lotus Notes through which we can access to particular mail field and add can content.

When the NSF file is created successfully the Arabic string (which is body) is displayed in left to right format, but that should be in right to left format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you with the right-to-left direction attribute, but I think you should try using the NotesRichTextItem class and its AppendText method instead of using the AppendItemValue.

I.e., something like this:

```
rtBody = new NotesRichtTextItem( MailDocument, "Body" )
call rtBody.AppendText( objMail.Body )
```

This will at least invoke code that is aware that Body is a rich text field instead of an ordinary plain text field, which is generally not the case when you use the AppendItemValue class.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, i have tried that too, but its direction is still left to right , can you tell me how can we change the indent of a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean right-to-left alignment, you can open the properties infobox of the body field, set the alignment property in the paragraph alignment tab.

Comment: "Info box of body field "

Comment: "Info box of body field" i didn't understand this, can you please explain me with an example.

Comment: Open the form containing the body field in designer, open the properties box of that body field and set the alignment property in the paragraph alignment tab.